# Switch the order of words using Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I found this code that switches YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY

```
b = re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})', '\\3-\\2-\\1', "2004-05-16")
```

So I'm trying to convert the string 'hey you man' to 'man hey you' but cannot do it.  I was able to group the string with:

```
b = re.findall(r'(\w+)', 'hey you man')
```

But when I do the following I get an error:

```
b = re.sub(r'(\w+)','\\3\\2\\1',"hey you man")
```

Also, I'm not interested in non-regex solutions.  I can switch the strings around using other methods, I'm just interested in learning about regexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture the words you want to switch in three separate groups (in your case, you have only one capture group); Here `\1`, `\2`, `\3` are back references referring to the captured groups (in parenthesis) in order, i.e. `\1 - hey`, `\2 - you`, `\3 - man`; By reordering these back references in the replacement, the words are reordered in the result:

```
re.sub(r'(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)', r'\3 \1 \2',"hey you man")
# 'man hey you'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I really appreciate it.  Why is it that in the date example there are two \\ whereas in yours there is only 1?

Comment: I declared it as a raw string with `r` so \ is not considered as an escape. In the date example, there's no `r` in front, so it needs double slashes.

Comment: @Psidom can you share a documentation about this?